# How does one practice suffering well?

Tags: suffering

Correct me if I'm wrong, I understand a lot of buddhism is about relieving of suffering through practicing of detachment. Removing detachment is a long process. Until one removes those attachments, there will still be suffering.

My question is: until one removes all of these attachments, one will suffer. How does one deal with these sufferings? Should one try to escape these sufferings in the moment? How does one suffer "well"? And not try to escape the sufferings?

Answer (score 5):

One will not get ride of suffering by simply trying to ignore or oppress. Attachment has craving as its cause and craving has ignorance as its cause. So one needs to gain insight, how things really are. To gain that, one does well to learn about the teachings of the Lord Buddha and then look for one self, if this is right, as well as to practice the way to clean the mind, so that it is able to concentrate it so that one is able to see.

What ever one sees, as it really is, inconstant, stressful, subject to change, one gets, disenchanted. *Disenchanted, he becomes dispassionate. Through dispassion, he is fully released. With full release, there is the knowledge, 'Fully released.' He discerns that 'Birth is ended, the holy life fulfilled, the task done. There is nothing further for this world.*

It's not possible to escape form suffering by developing such what is called "[householder-equanimity](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.137.than_en.html#household-eq6)" and suffering is actually a yogis friend, which does not mean that one tutors one self, but observer it and in this way one finds a way out without simply counteract in an unwholesome way, Mr Jason.

The practice start with things many estimate as child work, now most are not even able to make this there way of live, like practice generosity (giving, letting go material thing), Sila (virtue)... the whole palette of [meritorious deeds](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/wijesinghe/punna_en.html). There one is confronted with all his/here raw defilement of greed, dislike, stinginess, conceit. One has to work against the defilements all the time, while observing them well.

So please do not fall in the current promoted misinterpretations of non-reacting and simply developing a bunch of ignorance, calling it equanimity.

Last but not least, Atma likes "How does one practice suffering?" how ever, although it most important to know it well in all its aspects, its good not to forget to develop the path out of it as well.

Each noble truth has its certain task.

A good place to begin, actually has been always the first step is to follow good basic talks:

- [Better to Give than to Consume](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bettertogive_en.html)
- [Sensitivity through Generosity](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/sensitivity_en.html)

And put this things into practice. Joy and pleasure are granted, as well as much suffering at the beginning with it.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Comment: Sadhu Bhante, Sadhu

Answer (score 2):

To escape suffering maybe also try not trying to escape suffering.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: until one removes all of these attachments, one will suffer. How does one deal with these sufferings?

I think one deals with them by removing (trying to remove, continuing to remove) attachments.

"I feel tired, I didn't sleep well, I wish I wasn't tired" might be an example of an attachment (to an imagined or remembered state of not feeling tired).

The desire (to not feel tired) causes suffering (mis-match between what is and what's desired).

So recognize suffering ("I'm unhappy about this state") then recognize the cause of suffering ("because I'm desiring (a.k.a. thirsting for) something unreal"). After that you can start on the third noble truth i.e. cessation (cessation of that desire, and of the suffering caused by that desire).

Various other practices help with that:

- Doing sensible things; don't mis-behave (don't waste time, don't drink intoxicants)
- Understanding concepts like non-self
- Beware of your mood (if you go around feeling bad that can make things worse)
- Not avoiding things: note that you're feeling tired (or more specifically, not 'you' but note there's a transient thought of awareness of something being called tiredness)
- Taking a "middle way": if you're thirsty, then drink
- Care about other people, e.g. [Brahmavihara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmavihara), [Sila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_ethics), [Dana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%81na) (e.g. the Dalai Lama says, I won't look up an exact quote but approximately, says that caring about other people lets you feel good, and seeing himself as being like other people rather than special helps him escape what would be the prison of thinking selfishly about himself)
- Attempt to cultivate antidotes to suffering e.g. [Bhavana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavana)
- Beware of ['assembled' phenomena](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12691/254)
- Try to understand and live the goal (e.g. if your goal were to go to the park, you might keep your attention on the park and takes steps to reduce each separation between yourself and the park)

Comment: Well collected, Upasaka Chris. Atma sees only one blatant common mistake. The Park thing, meaning thinking of results rather to focus on the certain steps so that there are reasons at the first place, if the attention is simply on the particular step. Its very common to think in means of results, but that is always the problem, as it becomes a problem, when one forgets his aim. That is way it is said, step by step, no need to worry about the fruit.

Comment: Thank you Bhante, I hope I understand: you're saying that being aware of separation is or causes a problem, and that thinking about (future) results (instead of present steps) becomes a problem. I said the "Park thing" because I was suggesting that being aware of separation identifies the problem to detach from, and that being aware of the destination helps direct steps; I was thinking of the [Brahmana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn51/sn51.015.than.html).

Comment: As we can see in the canon, the Buddha did not merely run around telling about Nibbana, but stayed very close. Such actions will cause such, such such. And having faith that he had gained the goal, the people took on to make steps of this and that kind, looking on the ground (mind) and not ahead, aside or where ever. Don't forget, there are less actually liking to live the holly live at least, but thinking on better becoming. So when they think that the final aim will not be reached, they are not trained to look on the steps and outcomes within the existence, end not seeking for the aim...

Comment: ... at least, they think walking as usual and look for fruits on the road is fine. Good Sutta btw., for putting effort on the first place, Upasaka Chris.